# Not able to destroy service as agent-state is down

Tags: juju, maas

I am unable to destroy service as on of the unit agent says its down. I see that this bug has been fixed as stated here [unit destruction depends on unit agents](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1190715)
But I am not getting whats the solution to the problem?

I am running juju `1.13.3-raring-amd64`. Here is output of juju status,

```
quantum-gateway:
    charm: local:precise/quantum-gateway-56
    exposed: false
    life: dying
    units:
      quantum-gateway/0:
        agent-state: down
        agent-state-info: (installed)
        agent-version: 1.12.0
        life: dying
        machine: "20"
        public-address: opnw02.master
```

Comment: Can you post the actual output of juju status? Does this service have subordinates attached to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have an `agent-state: down` that means the bootstrap node can't communicate with the juju-agent. As a result it can't destroy as it can't communicate the next set of events.

This happens sometimes when the machine is destroyed outside of juju, so juju thinks it's still there though the machine has been physically removed. Can you confirm that opnw02.master is indeed still running? If so, try to ssh to it either using `juju ssh 20` or `ssh ubuntu@opnw02.master`. If you can gain access to the machine try restarting the juju-agents, which are `jujud-machine-#` and `jujud-unit-<service>-#`. So in your case the following commands will restart those services

```
sudo stop jujud-machine-20
sudo stop jujud-unit-quantum-gateway-0

sudo start jujud-machine-20
sudo start jujud-unit-quantum-gateway-0
```

At this point juju status should report the unit-agent as started again. You may need to run `juju resolved quantum-gateway/0` a few times as it appears to have stopped during mid-hook execution. Eventually, the service should go par to the course and be removed.

If you are unable to log in to the machine (either it was destroyed outside of juju, or for other reasons) then it'll remain in the juju status for now. There's work to allow "cleanup" of services but it hasn't landed yet (as of 1.13.3). If you want to deploy quantum-gateway again, and the status still has this agent-state down business, then you can deploy it with a different alias like so:

```
juju deploy quantum-gateway qgateway
```

Going forward you can make relations to it by issuing `juju add-relation nova-compute qgateway`

Comment: hi Marco, that was a prefect answer for me i think. I am not even able to ssh that server. I am curious to know when "cleanup" will be released? For time being I'll deploy it different alias.

Comment: @SaM I'm not entirely certain when it will land. It's been identified as an issue by the core team, but I don't know an exactly timeline, sadly. I'll try to remember to update this answer when it does land.

Comment: hi! I deployed again service again with qgateway alias, It installed OS And now its just stuck at agent-state-info: (installed), I am not even able to ssh, what can be issue here?